# Naming a list with a number

Tags: python, variables

Can you name a list with the first character being a number?  I get an error when I try to do this.  I am taking names of products and making lists and dictionaries with them and some of the names of the products start with a number.
like:

`11T25M = ["Grade", "Tensile", "Elongation"]`

I get

```
11T25M = ["Grade", "Tensile", "Elongation"]
     ^
Syntax Error: invalid decimal literal
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not allowed to start a variable name with a number, regardless of the type of the variable (i.e. not just lists), the parser disallows it. This is fairly common amongst a lot of languages.

`2e1` is a valid number in python (20), imagine if you wrote `my_var = 2e1`, is 2e1 a variable or a number? How is the parser to know?

Technically you could force a variable starting with a number for the name to exist through `globals()` but other than being terrible practice, it would be such a faff it's not worth the time or extra writing it would require.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot start a variable name with a number. One solution is instead of having a bunch of variables, you can contain them all in a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict["11T25M"] = ["Grade", "Tensile", "Elongation"]
print(my_dict["11T25M"])
```

Now instead of having a list called `11T25M`, you have a list called `my_dict["11T25M"]`